# Sending sender.currentTitle UIButton text to UILabel in PopUpViewController not sending to through to PopUpViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, segue, popover

I have two View Controllers.
The first UIViewController 'DiscrimUIViewCollection' has 5 buttons, each linked to one @IBAction func showAdvicePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) in the swift file.
I can use the print(sender.currentTitle) successfully and it prints out the title to each of the 5 buttons.

In the Second View Controller, 'PopUpViewContoller' I have a UILabel that I would like to set the Text of from the Title of the sender button from the first controller.

I have used various   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UIButton?)   commands, but the problem is that the 'PopUpViewController' just does not receive the 'sender.currentTitle' from the 'DiscrimUIViewCollection'.

I've been at this 2 days now and cannot find the answer.

I want the Value of    var updateTheLabel: String?    to receive the sender.currentTitle from the 'DiscrimUIViewCollection' and I think that it will all work.

I don't have any Segue arrows on the main.storyboard as I've done it all programmatically.

I've included the code below for you to review.

Thanks in advance.

```
class DiscrimUIViewCollection: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,   UICollectionViewDataSource {

public var buttonText = ""
@IBAction func showAdvicePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
 let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "advicePopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
 self.addChild(popOverVC)
 popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
 self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
 popOverVC.didMove(toParent: (self))
 buttonText = sender.currentTitle!

print(sender.currentTitle!)

print(buttonText) //THIS WORKS!


}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UIButton?) {
          //if segue.identifier == "advicePopUpID" {
           let controller = segue.destination as! PopUpViewController
             controller.updateTheLabel = buttonText
          //}
       }
}
```

And here is the PopUpViewController file:

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

// This file is to set the setting of the UIView Controller and how it appears.
//var desiredLabelValue: String?

var updateTheLabel: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)

    self.showAnimate()

    adviceTitle.text = updateTheLabel
    //print(updateTheLabel!)
    //adviceTitle?.text = desiredLabelValue

    //To set the text of Header
    //adviceTitle?.text = "Yellow Advice"

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: Any) {
    //self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    //self.removeAnimate()
    print(updateTheLabel)
}



func showAnimate() {


    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    //popUpArea.backgroundColor = colourOrange
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0

        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        //print(self.adviceText!)
        //print(self.adviceTitle!)
        //self.adviceTitle?.text = "Yellow Advice"

        //self.adviceTitle?.text = self.desiredLabelValue


        //print(self.adviceTitle?.text!)

        //Set the Background Colour of the popup box
        //depending on what the Title states.
        if self.adviceTitle.text == "Red Advice" {
            self.popUpArea.backgroundColor = mtsRed
        } else if self.adviceTitle?.text == "Orange Advice" {
            self.popUpArea.backgroundColor = mtsOrange
        } else if self.adviceTitle.text == "Yellow Advice" {
            self.popUpArea.backgroundColor = mtsYellow
        } else if self.adviceTitle.text == "Green Advice" {
            self.popUpArea.backgroundColor = mtsGreen
        } else if self.adviceTitle.text == "Blue Advice" {
            self.popUpArea.backgroundColor = mtsBlue
        }

    })
}


func removeAnimate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    }) { (success:Bool) in
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()

        }
    }

@IBOutlet weak var adviceTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var adviceText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var popUpArea: UIView!


}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you created segue programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present the popOverVC and pass the data. There is no need to assign it a frame and add it as a subview if you want to present it in fullscreen.

```
@IBAction func showAdvicePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "advicePopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
   buttonText = sender.currentTitle!
   popOverVC.updateTheLabel = buttonText
   popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen // to present on full screen
   self.present(popOverVC, animation : true, completion : nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes, superb!. This worked a treat!  I needed to keep some of the code as the PopOverVC child did not appear correctly and made the previous page unaccessible requiring me to swipe down to bring the page back.  Don't know what's going on there.  In fact, every page on the app I have a swipe down feature that takes me to the previous UIView Controller and I wish I could get ride of it, it's like it sits on top of the last UIView Contr. with a little bit of the previous it visible at the top of the screen.

Comment: yes that is the default behaviour of presenting view controller from iOS 13 onwords. you can make it fullscreen just by one line of code.  i have added it in the code.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  I found the settings in the Attributes settings under Presentation, so I just need to re-align the screen views now.  Brill! Thank you!

Comment: So, I am trying to implement the same principle in obtaining the Title Text from a UIButton to pass to a UILabel to a second ViewController using the same principles as above, fully expecting it to work, but it doesn't.  The title of the Button is able to be printed from within the button ViewController, but it just simple is not passed to the next VC.  I've been at this again two days and it's driving me crazy. I'm tried and adapted multiple samples from the internet and carefully adapted the code.  Any clues that could be given?  I can put the code up for this button if required. Thanks agn!

Comment: @David_2877 ask it in a new question and i would be glad to help. paste the link here.

Comment: @iOSArchitext.com Thank you, here's the link:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310762/send-titlelabel-from-uibutton-to-a-uilabel-in-a-different-uiview-controller-but

Comment: So is this code for passing data to another VC only suitable for passing to a PopUpVC and not a standard UIViewController?  As it only works on a PopUp and doesn't work on a UIVC with reference to my other problem passing the data onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code:

The PopOverVC animates in and out with other code and sets the UILabel within.

```
@IBAction func showAdvicePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "advicePopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
buttonText = sender.currentTitle!
popOverVC.updateTheLabel = buttonText
self.addChild(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParent: (self))
buttonText = sender.currentTitle!

}
```